# Google Maps changing a marker back to its original image

Tags: google-maps-api-3

A wee bit out of my depth here, I hope someone can help me resolve this...

I have a Google map which loads data from an array and also populates a sidebar list of the items.

A click on the sidebar item opens the corresponding infowindow as expected o.k.

When I mouseenter a sidebar item it pans to if necessary and highlights the corresponding marker (and closes any infowindow currently open ).

(.locs is the sidebar container, .loc is an item)

```
    $(document).on("mouseenter",".loc",function() {
    var thisloc = $(this).data("locid");
    for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
        if(markers[i].locid == thisloc) {  //get the latlong
            if(lastinfowindow instanceof google.maps.InfoWindow) lastinfowindow.close();
            map.panTo(markers[i].getPosition());
            markers[i].setIcon('../mapIcons/mini-white.png');
        }
    }
});
```

This bit works fine as I'm just setting a fixed image.
However, when I mouseleave the marker fails to revert back to its original state.
If I use the setIcon for a specic image it works fine, but I want to refer back to the original icon from the dataset item.

```
markers[i].setIcon("currmark");
```

currmark is the var I used to hold the original icon.

```
$(document).on("mouseleave",".loc",function() {
    var thisloc = $(this).data("locid");
    var currmark = getIcon("mapData.type");
    for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
        if(markers[i].locid == thisloc) {  //get the latlong
            map.panTo(markers[i].getPosition());
            markers[i].setIcon("currmark");
        }
    }
});
```

An alert set on 'currmark', the var I used to hold the original icon, shows only the last icon set by the mouseenter setIcon.
This seems to idicate to me that the original icon from the dataset (mapdata.type) has been forgotten / replaced by the last setting applied to markers[i].
I think I need to reaccess the dataset to remind the var of the original state when I set

```
    var currmark = getIcon("mapData.type");
```

Some added info....

I'm using a utility function that translates a given 'type' in the dataset to an icon, hence the getIcon(type) function.

```
function getIcon(type) {
switch(type) {
    case "bar": return "../mapIcons/mini-blue.png";
    case "restaurant": return "../mapIcons/mini-red.png";
    case "cafe": return "../mapIcons/mini-yellow.png";
    default: return "../mapIcons/mini-white.png";
}
}
```

An example of a data entry...

```
var data = [
{address:'Rua  Calheta',detail:'Restaurant',title:'Dolphin',type:'restaurant',ico:'red',lat:"37.08570947136275",long:"-8.731633722782135"}
];
```

I hope I've explained this half sensibly. Can anyone assist me, as I was dead chuffed I'd got this far.

2nd Additional Info for Beetroot showing how my marker and sidebar are initially setup....

```
data.forEach(function(mapData,idx) {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, 
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapData.lat,mapData.long),
                    title: mapData.title,
                    icon: getIcon(mapData.type)
                });
                var link=('<a href="#"' + mapData.title +'">');
                var contentHtml = "<div id='iw' class='iw2'><h3>" + link + mapData.title+"</a></h3>" + mapData.detail+"<br>"+mapData.address+"</div>";
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentHtml
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    if(lastinfowindow instanceof google.maps.InfoWindow) lastinfowindow.close();
                    marker.infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    lastinfowindow = marker.infowindow;                        
                });
                marker.locid = idx+1;
                marker.infowindow = infowindow;
                markers[markers.length] = marker;
                var spot=('<img src="' + (getIcon(mapData.type)) + '" />');

                var sideHtml = '<p class="loc" data-locid="'+marker.locid+'">'+spot+mapData.title+'</p>';
                     $("#locs").append(sideHtml); 

                if(markers.length == data.length) doFilter();

});
```

---

**EDIT 02/07**
The complete source after incorporating Beetroot-Beetroot's slick changes. Here in its entirety as I'm now **vary aware** that he can only help if he has the whole picture!
Now attempting to debug after learning I'm not such a smartass.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false& style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var markers = [];
var lastinfowindow;
var locIndex;

 //Credit: MDN
if ( !Array.prototype.forEach ) {
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
    fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
    }
  }
}

//my data ~ cutdown and local for testing 
var data = [
{address:'Rua Calheta',detail:'Restaurant',title:'Dolphin',type:'restaurant',icotyp:'red',lat:"37.08570947136275",long:"-8.731633722782135"},
{address:'Rua Calheta',detail:'Cafe',title:'Cafe Calheta',type:'cafe',icotyp:'yellow',lat:"37.0858150589029",long:"-8.731550574302673"},
{address:'Rua Calheta',detail:'Bar',title:'Kellys',type:'bar',icotyp:'red',lat:"37.08583217639933",long:"-8.731239438056945"},
{address:'Rua 2nd Abril',detail:'Bar',title:'Godots',type:'bar',icotyp:'blue',lat:"37.08602046860496",long:"-8.731470108032226"}
];

// translate data type: to icon
function getIcon(type) {
 switch(type) {
    case "bar": return "../mapIcons/mini-blue.png";
    case "restaurant": return "../mapIcons/mini-red.png";
    case "cafe": return "../mapIcons/mini-yellow.png";
    default: return "../mapIcons/mini-white.png";
 }
}

function initialize() {
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.08597981464561, -8.730670809745788);
 var myOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

   // revised beetroot-beetroot 'loop' function to set markers and sidebar at the same time

var $locs = $("#locs");//Used repeatedly inside the loop.

$.each(data, function(idx, mapData) {
//Note: critical assignment of the new marker as a property of `mapData`.
mapData.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapData.lat,mapData.long),
    title: mapData.title,
    icon: getIcon(mapData.type)
});
var link = '<a href="#"' + mapData.title +'">' + mapData.title + '</a>';
var contentHtml = "<div id='iw' class='iw2'><h3>" + link + "</h3>" + mapData.detail + "<br>" + mapData.address + "</div>";

//What was `marker` must now be referred to as `mapData.marker`
mapData.marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentHtml
});
google.maps.event.addListener(mapData.marker, 'click', function() {
    if(lastinfowindow && lastinfowindow.close) lastinfowindow.close();
    //`this` refers back to the clicked element; the appropriate marker
    this.infowindow.open(map, this);
    lastinfowindow = this.infowindow;
});

var spot = '<img src="' + (getIcon(mapData.type)) + '" />';

//Here, it's convenient to create what was `sideitem` as a jQuery object, so we can apply several jquery methods (without making an assignment).
$('<p class="loc" />')
    .html(spot + mapData.title)
    .appendTo($locs)
    .data('mapData', mapData);//<<<<<<<< critical

});

doFilter(); //It should be possible to execute this statement when the loop is finished.

$(document).on("mouseenter", ".loc", function() {
if(lastinfowindow && lastinfowindow.close) lastinfowindow.close();
var mapData = $(this).data("mapData");
map.panTo(mapData.marker.getPosition());//<<<< direct reference to the marker avoids the need to loop.
mapData.marker.setIcon(getIcon(''));//get the default icon.
}).on("mouseleave", ".loc", function() {
var mapData = $(this).data("mapData");
mapData.marker.setIcon(getIcon(mapData.type));
}).on("click",".loc",function() {
var mapData = $(this).data("mapData");
mapData.marker.infowindow.open(map, mapData.marker);
 lastinfowindow = mapData.marker.infowindow;
});

/*
Run on every change to any of the checkboxes
*/

 function doFilter() {

if(lastinfowindow && lastinfowindow.close) lastinfowindow.close(); //Close last info windows if still open and new filter applied
     if(!locIndex) {
         locIndex = {};
         //I reverse index markers to figure out the position of loc to marker index
         for(var x=0, len=markers.length; x<len; x++) {
             locIndex[markers[x].locid] = x;
        }
    }

    //what's checked?
    var checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
    var selTypes = [];
    for(var i=0, len=checked.length; i<len; i++) {
        selTypes.push($(checked[i]).val());
     }
     for(var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++) {
        var sideDom = "p.loc[data-locid="+(i+1)+"]";

         //Only hide if length != 0
         if(checked.length !=0 && selTypes.indexOf(data[i].type) < 0) {
             $(sideDom).hide();
            markers[locIndex[i+1]].setVisible(false);
        } else {
             $(sideDom).show();
            markers[locIndex[i+1]].setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}

$(document).on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", doFilter);
}

</script>
<style type="text/css">
#container {width:920px;height:500px; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}

#map_canvas {width: 700px; height: 500px;float:left;border:1px gray solid;margin-right:10px;}

/* sidebar styling */
#locs {margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 0px;margin-left: 5px;height: 500px;width:200px;overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: hidden;}
#locs img {float:left;padding-right:5px;}
.loc {border: 0;width: 200px;padding: 2px;cursor: pointer;margin:0;text-transform:uppercase;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:0.90em;}

/* checkbox styling */
#form {margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 0px;height: 29px;}
.label {width: 32.5%;margin: 0;padding: 4px 0 4px 4px;display: inline-block;font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 0.75em;font-weight: bold;}
.red {color:white;background-color:red;}
.yellow {color:yellow;background-color:black;}
.blue {color:white;background-color:blue;}

/* Map info styling */
#map_canvas div#iw {width:250px;height:65px;overflow:hidden;}
#map_canvas h3 {font-size:1em; margin:0; padding:3px;}
#map_canvas .iw2 a {text-decoration:none;border-bottom:thin blue dashed;}
#map_canvas .iw2 a:hover {text-decoration:none;border-bottom:thin red solid;}
</style>
</head>

<body onLoad="initialize()">
<div id="container">

<div id="map_canvas"></div> <!-- map //-->
<div id="locs"></div> <!-- sidebar //-->

<div id="form" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:thin gray solid;width:910px">
<span class="label blue"><input type="checkbox" name="bars" value="bar">Bars</span>
<span class="label yellow"><input type="checkbox" name="cafes" value="cafe">Cafes</span>
<span class="label red"><input type="checkbox" name="restaurants" value="restaurant">Restaurants</span>
</div>

</div> <!-- end of container //-->
</body>
</html>
```

---

EDIT 3 - 03/07 - Revised initialise marker / sidebar

```
// BB - revised  each loop function to set markers and sidebar at the same time

var $locs = $("#locs");//Used repeatedly inside the loop.

$.each(data, function(idx, mapData) {
//BB - Note: critical assignment of the new marker as a property of `mapData`.
    mapData.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapData.lat,mapData.long),
        title: mapData.title,
        icon: getIcon(mapData.type)
    });

var link = '<a href="#"' + mapData.title +'">' + mapData.title + '</a>';
var contentHtml = "<div id='iw' class='iw2'><h3>" + link + "</h3>" + mapData.detail + "<br>" + mapData.address + "</div>";

//What was `marker` must now be referred to as `mapData.marker`
mapData.marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentHtml
});
google.maps.event.addListener(mapData.marker, 'click', function() {
    if(lastinfowindow && lastinfowindow.close) lastinfowindow.close();
    //BB - `this` refers back to the clicked element; the appropriate marker
    this.infowindow.open(map, this);
    lastinfowindow = this.infowindow;
});

//BB - Here, it's convenient to create what was `sideitem` as a jQuery object, so we can apply several jquery methods (without making an assignment).
var spot = '<img src="' + (getIcon(mapData.type)) + '" />';
$('<p class="loc" />')
    .html(spot + mapData.title)
    .appendTo($locs)
    .data('mapData', mapData);//<<<<<<<< critical

//BB - At the bottom of the $.each() loop in initialize(), create and populate one array per category, as properties of markers ://
if(!markers[mapData.type]) markers[mapData.type] = [];
markers[mapData.type].push(mapData.marker);
});

// End of for/each loop
```

---

EDIT 4 - 07/07 - Revised full script for comment

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
//var markers = [];
//object, not array. BB
var markers = {};
var lastinfowindow;
//var locIndex;

//Credit: MDN
  if ( !Array.prototype.forEach ) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
      for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
        fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
      }
   }
}

//my data ~ cutdown and local for testing 
var data = [
{address:'Rua Calheta',detail:'South African &amp; Portuguese Restaurant',title:'Dolphin',type:'restaurant',lat:"37.08570947136275",long:"-8.731633722782135"},
{address:'Rua Calheta',detail:'Poruguese Cafe / Bar',title:'Cafe Calheta',type:'cafe',lat:"37.0858150589029",long:"-8.731550574302673"},
{address:'Rua Calheta',detail:'English Bar',title:'Kellys',type:'bar',lat:"37.08583217639933",long:"-8.731239438056945"},
{address:'Rua 2nd Abril',detail:'English Bar',title:'Godots',type:'bar',lat:"37.08602046860496",long:"-8.731470108032226"},
{address:'Rua 2nd Abril',detail:'Chinese Restaurant',title:'Royal Garden',type:'restaurant',lat:"37.086164896968405",long:"-8.731738328933715"},
{address:'Rua 2nd Abril',detail:'English Bar',title:'Clives',type:'bar',lat:"37.086125",long:"-8.731374"},
{address:'Rua 2nd Abril',detail:'English Restaurant',title:'The Lime Tree',type:'restaurant',lat:"37.086125877750365",long:"-8.731588125228881"},
{address:'Praia da Luz',detail:'Portuguese Restaurant',title:'Alloro',type:'restaurant',lat:"37.09158",long:"-8.724850"},
{address:'Rua Calheta',detail:'English Cafe / Bistro',title:'Jakes',type:'cafe',lat:"37.0862601125538",long:"-8.732671737670898"},
{address:'Av dos Pescadores',detail:'English &amp; Portuguese Restaurant',title:'Chaplins',type:'restaurant',lat:"37.08550480361006",long:"-8.730005621910095"},
{address:'Av dos Pescadores',detail:'English &amp; Portuguese Restaurant',title:'Atlantico',type:'restaurant',lat:"37.085425634814705",long:"-8.729941248893737"},
{address:'Av dos Pescadores',detail:'Indian Restaurant',title:'Saffron',type:'restaurant',lat:"37.08534432623613",long:"-8.729884922504425"},
{address:'Av dos Pescadores',detail:'Indian Restaurant',title:'Pashmina',type:'restaurant',lat:"37.08526729697597",long:"-8.729839324951171"},
{address:'Rua Calheta',detail:'English Bar',title:'The Bull',type:'bar',lat:"37.085652442494",long:"-8.73089075088501"},
{address:'Av dos Pescadores',detail:'English &amp; Portuguese Restaurant',title:'Galley',type:'restaurant',lat:"37.08571577732778",long:"-8.729227781295776"},
{address:'Av dos Pescadores',detail:'English &amp; Portuguese Bar',title:'Carlos',type:'bar',lat:"37.0856306176238",long:"-8.729227781295776"}
];

// translate data.type: to icon
function getIcon(type) {
switch(type) {
    case "bar": return "../mapIcons/mini-blue.png";
    case "restaurant": return "../mapIcons/mini-red.png";
    case "cafe": return "../mapIcons/mini-green.png";
    default: return "../mapIcons/mini-white.png"; // used as current selection indicator
    //default: return "../mapIcons/marker-yellow-dot.png"; // will use instead of white later
}
}

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.08597981464561, -8.730670809745788);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
Start of for/each loop 
*/

var $locs = $("#locs");//Used repeatedly inside the loop.

$.each(data, function(idx, mapData) {
//BB - Note: critical assignment of the new marker as a property of `mapData`.
// section 1 - Marker construct    
     mapData.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapData.lat,mapData.long),
        title: mapData.title,
        icon: getIcon(mapData.type)
    });
// section 1 end

// section 2 - Infowindow construct
    var link = '<a href="#"' + mapData.title +'">' + mapData.title + '</a>'; // make a link of name
    var contentHtml = "<div id='iw' class='iw2'><h3>" + link + "</h3>" + mapData.detail + "</div>"; // style info window and add detail
// What was `marker` must now be referred to as `mapData.marker`
    mapData.marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentHtml,
    });
// section 2 end

// section 3 - Map marker click function
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapData.marker, 'click', function() { 
        if(lastinfowindow && lastinfowindow.close) lastinfowindow.close(); // close any open infowindows
        map.setZoom(18); // zoom in
        map.setCenter(mapData.marker.getPosition());// centre on selection
    //BB - `this` refers back to the clicked element; the appropriate marker
        this.infowindow.open(map, this);  // open infowindow
        lastinfowindow = this.infowindow; // remember for closing this infowindow, if still open when selection changes
    });
// section 3 end

// section 4 - Display Map marker and sidebar item
// BB - Here, it's convenient to create what was `sideitem` as a jQuery object, so we can apply several jquery methods (without making an assignment).
    var spot = '<img src="' + (getIcon(mapData.type)) + '" />'; // sidebar copy of marker for display
    $('<p class="loc" />')
        .html(spot + mapData.title) // sidebar icon and name
        .appendTo($locs) // add to sidebar container
        .data('mapData', mapData);  //<<<<<<<< critical
// BB Remove non matching from sidebar   
        marker.loc = $('<p class="loc" />').addClass(mapData.type).html(spot + mapData.title).data('marker', {m:marker, type:mapData.type}).appendTo($locs).get(0);
// BB - At the bottom of the $.each() loop in initialize(), create and populate one array per category, as properties of markers ://
        if(!markers[mapData.type]) markers[mapData.type] = [];
        markers[mapData.type].push(marker);
});

// End of for/each loop    
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

} // end of initialise (?)

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
Sidebar Functions
*/

$(document).on("mouseenter", ".loc", function() {
   //if(lastinfowindow && lastinfowindow.close) lastinfowindow.close(); // moved to on click, avoids closing when accidently moving mouse
      var mapData = $(this).data("mapData");
       map.setZoom(18); // zoom in a bit
       map.setCenter(mapData.marker.getPosition());// centre on selection
     //map.panTo(mapData.marker.getPosition());// direct reference to the marker avoids the need to loop.
       mapData.marker.setIcon(getIcon(''));//get the default icon ie. larger yellow spot.
    }).on("mouseleave", ".loc", function() {
       var mapData = $(this).data("mapData");
       mapData.marker.setIcon(getIcon(mapData.type));//reset marker to correct type
       map.setZoom(17); //rest zoom to default
       map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()); // centre on map middle
    }).on("click", ".loc", function() { // opens corresponding info window on map
       if(lastinfowindow && lastinfowindow.close) lastinfowindow.close();
       var mapData = $(this).data("mapData");
     //map.setZoom(19); // zoom in more maybe
       mapData.marker.infowindow.open(map, mapData.marker); // open infowindow
       lastinfowindow = mapData.marker.infowindow; // remember for closing this infowindow, if still open when selection changes
})

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
Run on every change to any of the checkboxes
*/  

function doFilter() {
    if(lastinfowindow && lastinfowindow.close) lastinfowindow.close(); // close last infowindow if still open
    alert ("filter triggered");
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, checkbox) {
        var markersArr = markers[checkbox.value];
        if(markersArr) {
            $.each(markersArr, function(i, marker) {
                marker.loc.style.display = ['none', 'block'][Number(checkbox.checked)]; // don't display non selected types
                marker.setVisible(checkbox.checked); // display selected type(s)
            });
        };
    });
}
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
Run on initial setup
*/      
  doFilter();

       //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
fires on every checkbox change
*/

  $("#form").on("click", ".cat", doFilter)

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, in the loop where the markers are created, you give each sidebar item a reference to its marker instead of the locid, then there's no need to loop to rediscover the marker on mouseenter/mouseleave.

ie, instead of setting :

```js
//My best guess at what the statement must be.
thisloc.data("locid", id);
//Keep this line if thisloc.data("locid") is used elsewhere.
```

set (within the sidebar item/marker creation loop) :

```js
var marker = ....;
var thisloc = ...;
...
data[i].marker = marker;//add a .marker property to the original dataset.
thisloc.data("itemData", data[i]);//associate the original dataset with the sidebar item
```

Now the mouseenter/mouseleave handlers should simplify as follows:

```js
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".loc", function() {
    if(lastinfowindow && lastinfowindow.close) lastinfowindow.close();
    var data = $(this).data("itemData");
    map.panTo(data.marker.getPosition());//<<<< direct reference to the marker avoids the need to loop.
    data.marker.setIcon(getIcon(''));//get the default icon.
}).on("mouseleave", ".loc", function() {
    var data = $(this).data("itemData");
    data.marker.setIcon(getIcon(data.type));
});
```

Note: You shouldn't need to pan to the marker again on mouseleave.

This should answer the question posed plus other advantages.

### EDIT:

OK, now I've seen the main loop, it can be revised something like this, with various mods all through :

```js
var $locs = $("#locs");//Used repeatedly inside the loop.

$.each(data, function(idx, mapData) {
    //Note: critical assignment of the new marker as a property of `mapData`.
    mapData.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapData.lat,mapData.long),
        title: mapData.title,
        icon: getIcon(mapData.type)
    });
    var link = '<a href="#"' + mapData.title +'">' + mapData.title + '</a>';
    var contentHtml = "<div id='iw' class='iw2'><h3>" + link + "</h3>" + mapData.detail + "<br>" + mapData.address + "</div>";

    //What was `marker` must now be referred to as `mapData.marker`
    mapData.marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentHtml
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapData.marker, 'click', function() {
        if(lastinfowindow && lastinfowindow.close) lastinfowindow.close();
        //`this` refers back to the clicked element; the appropriate marker
        this.infowindow.open(map, this);
        lastinfowindow = this.infowindow;
    });

    var spot = '<img src="' + (getIcon(mapData.type)) + '" />';

    //Here, it's convenient to create what was `sideitem` as a jQuery object, so we can apply several jquery methods (without making an assignment).
    $('<p class="loc" />')
        .html(spot + mapData.title)
        .appendTo($locs)
        .data('mapData', mapData);//<<<<<<<< critical

});
doFilter();//It should be possible to execute this statement when the loop is finished.
```

And the corresponding mouseenter/mouseleave handlers would be :

```js
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".loc", function() {
    if(lastinfowindow && lastinfowindow.close) lastinfowindow.close();
    var mapData = $(this).data("mapData");
    map.panTo(mapData.marker.getPosition());//<<<< direct reference to the marker avoids the need to loop.
    mapData.marker.setIcon(getIcon(''));//get the default icon.
}).on("mouseleave", ".loc", function() {
    var mapData = $(this).data("mapData");
    mapData.marker.setIcon(getIcon(mapData.type));
});
```

*All untested, so may well need debugging.*

### EDIT2 :

The way I left it above, the array `markers` wasn't being populated. Now I have seen the function `doFilter()` I can see that `markers` should be populated, however it is more convenient for it to be an object rather than an array.

```
markers = {};//in the same scope as before
```

At the bottom of the `$.each()` loop in `initialize()`, create and populate one array per category, as properties of `markers` :

```
if(!markers[mapData.type]) markers[mapData.type] = [];
markers[mapData.type].push(mapData.marker);
```

With the `markers` populated in this way, you have a very simple means of identifying all markers in each category, and `doFilter()` will simplify enormously to :

```
function doFilter() {
    if(lastinfowindow && lastinfowindow.close) lastinfowindow.close();
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, checkbox) {
        var markersArr = markers[checkbox.value];
        if(markersArr) {
            $.each(markersArr, function(i, marker) {
                marker.setVisible(checkbox.checked);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

### EDIT3

To get the sidebar entries to show/hide in sympathy with the category controls, `initialize()` should be as follows :

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.08597981464561, -8.730670809745788);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var $locs = $("#locs");//Used repeatedly inside the loop.

    var marker;
    $.each(data, function(idx, mapData) {
        //Note: critical assignment of the new marker as a property of `mapData`.
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapData.lat, mapData.long),
            title: mapData.title,
            icon: getIcon(mapData.type)
        });
        var link = '<a href="#"' + mapData.title +'">' + mapData.title + '</a>';
        var contentHtml = "<div id='iw' class='iw2'><h3>" + link + "</h3>" + mapData.detail + "<br>" + mapData.address + "</div>";

        marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentHtml
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            closeLastInfoWindow();
            //`this` refers back to the clicked element; the appropriate marker
            this.infowindow.open(map, this);
            lastinfowindow = this.infowindow;
        });

        var spot = '<img src="' + (getIcon(mapData.type)) + '" />';

        //Here, it's convenient to create what was `sideitem` as a jQuery object, so we can apply several jquery methods.
        marker.loc = $('<p class="loc" />')
            .addClass(mapData.type)
            .html(spot + mapData.title)
            .data('marker', {m:marker, type:mapData.type})
            .appendTo($locs).get(0);
        if(!markers[mapData.type]) markers[mapData.type] = [];
            markers[mapData.type].push(marker);
    });

    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".loc", function() {
        closeLastInfoWindow();
        var m = $(this).data("marker").m;
        map.panTo(m.getPosition());//<<<< direct reference to the marker avoids the need to loop.
        m.setIcon(getIcon(''));//get the default icon.
    }).on("mouseleave", ".loc", function() {
        var data = $(this).data("marker");
        data.m.setIcon(getIcon(data.type));
    }).on("click",".loc",function() {
        var m = $(this).data("marker").m;
        m.infowindow.open(map, m);
        lastinfowindow = m.infowindow;
    });
    $("#form").on("click", ".cat", doFilter);

    doFilter();
}
```

Comment: Certainly added other advantages! I was leaving the optimising until I got it working, however this solution is more 'readable'.

Comment: I've edited my original post to show how my markers and sidebar are setup as I'm failing to get the association of marker and sidebar.

Comment: Neil, thanks for the extra code. Take a look at my edit above.

Comment: I've edited the original post with a copy of the complete source, not to try and get you to finish it off but to show you the whole picture. Now very aware that you can only work with the info supplied! I've incorporated your changes and managed to bust the sidebar operation. So have included the doFilter, and on Click functions. The map loads fine complete with sidebar and opens infowindows from within the map, but the sidebar is dead. I'm working through the changes but as its pretty much a rewrite I'm learning all over again. I really do appreciate you taking the time to help sort this.

Comment: It's a bit worrying that the sidebar should be dead. I'm sure it's something simple but I can't spot it. I would need to run the whole page. Meanwhile, I have added "Edit2" above, with a suggested approach to handling categories.

Comment: With the structural changes I think marker as an object rather than array seems more accessable and will give this a tryout. As for the dead sidebar I reckon its down to my merging the click function in with the mouseenter and leave functions so am dissecting that area first.

Comment: After changing the icon urls, my own local version worked first time so there's nothing majorly wrong.

Comment: Oh yes, I moved `doFilter()` below the function definition, otherwise an error would be thrown.

Comment: 24hrs later..Slowly getting to the bottom of this 'work of art', but still have a problem(s). Could I ask you to look at the edit3 revision of my post. How does the each loop differ to your 'local version' ( as yours works:)) My sidebar populates ok complete with copy of marker, the sidebar mouseenter now pans map ok but there are no markers on the map at all. A touch of code blindness methinks.

Comment: Hi Neil, if I paste your code into my local file, then it works exactly the same. Apart from the comments, that block of code is identical. No markers come up initially, but do so once one or more categories are selected. Your `doFilter()` should be fine if it's the same as in my edit2 above. The only thing that needs fixing (in my local version) is that the sidebar shows the full list all the time regardless of which categories are selected and, onmoseover, the map pans to invisible markers.

Comment: Removing the solo 'doFilter' shows all markers on map and sidebar on start up ok, mouseenter/leave o.k. Now checking why any Click on sidebar item fails to open corresponding info window. Also Checkbox click fails to filter anything.

Comment: $(document).on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", doFilter); // should fire on every checkbox change
 only fires on a screen refresh

Comment: Sorry last timed out.    $(document).on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", doFilter); // should trigger the doFilter on every checkbox state change but only fires after a state change and a F5 screen refresh. The doFilter function does now run correctly on initial page load, any ideas?

Comment: In my local version, I have `class="cat"` in each of the three category inputs, and the handler is attached with `$("#form").on("click", ".cat", doFilter)`.

Comment: missing brace solved checkbox trigger. ff debug didn't pick it up ie did (theres a pleasant change).

Comment: I will stop asking questions v.soon. How do I identify the type relationship with the .loc item in order to remove the unselected type items from the sidebar? Just cant see how to access the .loc 'array'.

Comment: I just have a couple of extra lines for that. Where the sidebar entries are created, each one is assigned to `mapData.marker.loc` and is given a class with `.addClass(mapData.type)`. Then in `doFilter()`, inside the `$.each(markersArr ...` loop, I have the additional line `marker.loc.style.display = ['none', 'block'][Number(checkbox.checked)];`.

Comment: var spot = '<img src="' + (getIcon(mapData.type)) + '" />';
        $('<p class="loc" />')
            .html(spot + mapData.title)
            .appendTo($locs)
            .data('mapData', mapData); 
         mapData.marker.loc = ('<p class="loc" />'); 
         $(mapData.marker.loc).addClass(mapData.type);    
 
    if(!markers[mapData.type]) markers[mapData.type] = [];
    markers[mapData.type].push(mapData.marker);
    }); // like so?

Comment: Nearly, `marker.loc = $('<p class="loc" />').addClass(mapData.type).html(spot + mapData.title).data('marker', {m:marker, type:mapData.type}).appendTo($locs).get(0);
if(!markers[mapData.type]) markers[mapData.type] = [];
markers[mapData.type].push(marker);`

Comment: var spot = '<img src="' + (getIcon(mapData.type)) + '" />';
// replaced by new BB marker.loc line?
//    $('<p class="loc" />')
//        .html(spot + mapData.title)
//        .appendTo($locs)
//        .data('mapData', mapData);//<<<<<<<< critical       --- New replacement line breaks after first marker displayed on map and sidebar with marker undefined?

Comment: Sorry BB, have added updated full script (above) as it stands at the moment. First marker displayed and functioning correctly. Still no looping cos of undefined marker error.

Comment: Sorry, there's another change. I decided against assigning markers to `mapData.marker` as there's now the potential for a "circular reference" (marker refers to loc and loc refers to marker), which is very bad for memory management in IE. Therefore, revert `mapData.marker` to `marker` all through. I don't think there are any other changes but I may be wrong - I tidied my local version quite a bit.

Comment: ... but of course, there are some other changes, in the loc event handlers. See my edit 3 above. Note also where my `initialize(){...}` function closes.

Comment: Looking absolutely most excellent! I want to extend / fit bounds to tidy up, having added     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); outside the loop, assume something like after the markers[mapData.type].push(marker);
//add this?          bounds.extend(markers[mapData.type]); if thats correct where would I then put the //    map.fitBounds(bounds) bit?

Comment: Bounds need to be applied in `doFilter()`, where you have two nested loops. Outside (above) the outer loop, set `var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()`. Inside the inner loop, if the checkbox is checked, extend the bounds to encompass `marker.getPosition()`. Outside (below) the outer loop, fit the map to the bounds but only `if(!bounds.isEmpty())`. Try it with and without testing `.isEmpty()` and see the difference.

Comment: sorry, trip to hospital 'normal' service resumed. am catching up now.

Answer (score 0):

`markers[i].setIcon("currmark")` won't work (sets the icon to the string "currmark").  Use the variable: `markers[i].setIcon(currmark)`.

```
$(document).on("mouseleave",".loc",function() {
    var thisloc = $(this).data("locid");
    var currmark = getIcon("mapData.type");
    for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
        if(markers[i].locid == thisloc) {  //get the latlong
            map.panTo(markers[i].getPosition());
            markers[i].setIcon(currmark);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the correction, still no joy as var currmark still contains the last setIcon state set by mouseenter "../mapIcons/mini-white.png"